# XSLT 1.0 to remove leading and trailing spaces

Tags: xslt, trim

I have to remove leading and trailing spaces  using XSL 1.0

cannot use  normalize-space for this .

and tried the below code

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
<xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'^\s+|\s+$','')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

before  commands to start the actual mapping

but does not help

how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is to use `normalize-space()`
function (works even in **XSLT 1.0**).

It does even more, i.e. it replaces multiple white chars **inside**
with a **single** space.

To apply it to all text nodes, add such a template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But if you have also the *identity template*, the above template
must be in your script **after** the *identity template*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in **XSLT 1.0**, you can use *recursive template* (NOT preferable) method to remove leading and trailing spaces **(In case you don't want to use `normalize-space()`)**

Let's assume your input as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <h1>                A text having so many leading and trailing spaces!           </h1>
</body>
```

**Note:** The below solution uses `xmlns:str="xalan://org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils"` to use it's two functions `ends-with` and `substringBeforeLast`

An XSLT 1.0 solution to achieve the task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="xalan://org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils" 
exclude-result-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1">
    <h1>
        <xsl:variable name="leadingSpaceRemoved">
            <xsl:call-template name="removeLeadingSpace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="trailingSpaceRemoved">
            <xsl:call-template name="removeTrailingSpace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$leadingSpaceRemoved" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="$trailingSpaceRemoved" />
    </h1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="removeLeadingSpace">
    <xsl:param name="text" />

    <xsl:variable name="h1" select="$text" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with($h1,' ')">
            <xsl:call-template name="removeLeadingSpace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($h1,' ')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$h1" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="removeTrailingSpace">
    <xsl:param name="text" />

    <xsl:variable name="h1" select="$text" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="str:ends-with($h1,' ')">
            <xsl:call-template name="removeTrailingSpace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="str:substringBeforeLast($h1,' ')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$h1" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Also, if you can call a java library/class in your environment, it will be more easier to achieve the same as below:**

Your XSLT would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:stringparser="xalan://com.example.commons.xsl.StringUtil"
exclude-result-prefixes="stringparser">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1">
    <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="stringparser:trim(.)" />
    </h1>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the **StringUtil.java** would be:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
public class StringUtil {
/**
 * 
 * @param input
 * @return remove leading and trailing spaces.
 */
public static String trim(final String input) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(input)) {
        return input.trim();
    }
    return input;
}
}
```