# How to remove last N character using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have following code

<xsl:value-of select=concat(substring(DBColumn, string-length(DBColumn)-3),concat('-',DBColumn))

It results me

230-Virginia-230.

I want it as 230-Virginia.

Originally in database it is as Virginia-230

Furthermore

ABC, 230-Virginia

How to trim whitespace in the same mentioned code so that it should look like as follow ABC,230-Virginia

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and clarify the logic you want to apply.

Comment: Please always say which XSLT version you are using. String manipulation becomes much easier in later versions.

Comment: Note that for a full statement of requirement we need to know how the code should handle strings other than `Virginia-230`. What happens for example, with strings containing no hyphens or several.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly your question is.

To answer the question as stated in your title: you can remove the last N characters from a string using:

```
substring($string, 1, string-length($string) - $N)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to illustrate with an input document that contains the data that you mentioned:

```
<input>
  <DBColumn>Virginia-230</DBColumn>
  <other>ABC </other> <!-- N.B. trailing space -->
</input>
```

This XSLT 3.0 stylesheet does some of the things that you mentioned in the "proposed value".  I've also included the input value and the "old-value" with the value-of expression that you mentioned in your post.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
      <input-value><xsl:value-of select="DBColumn" /></input-value>
      <old-output-value>
        <xsl:value-of 
             select="concat(substring(DBColumn, string-length(DBColumn)-3),
                     concat('-', DBColumn))"/>
      </old-output-value>
      <proposed-value>
        <xsl:value-of 
             select="normalize-space(other) 
                     || ',' ||
                     string-join(reverse(tokenize(DBColumn, '-')), '-')"
                  />
      </proposed-value>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces:

```
<output>
   <input-value>Virginia-230</input-value>
   <old-output-value>-230-Virginia-230</old-output-value>
   <proposed-value>ABC,230-Virginia</proposed-value>
</output>
```

For an xsl:value-of() that I believe works in XSLT1.0 (but I won't guarantee), you could try:

```
<xsl:value-of 
             select="concat(other, ',', 
                            substring-after(DBColumn, '-'), 
                            '-',
                            substring-before(DBColumn, '-'))" />
```

which does not address the trailing space in `other` but at least suggests how to reverse the two values around the '-' char in DBColumn.

For suggestions on removing leading/trailing spaces on string, see: [XSLT 1.0 to remove leading and trailing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54798694/xslt-1-0-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-spaces)

Comment: Thank you, i am using 1.0 version

Comment: Does it have any one liner function?

Comment: I've edited the my response to propose an xslt1.0 version.